# Is there any way I can use objs = Model.objects.raw(sql) with PageNumberPagination in django rest framework without passing list(objs) to pagination

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination

I'm currently facing a challenge with pagination while using raw SQL queries in Django. The situation arose when I needed to apply an additional filter in the LEFT OUTER JOIN of my query, which I found wasn't directly supported by Django's ORM. Despite attempting to use FilteredRelation, I realized that it didn't fully meet my requirements.

As a workaround, I opted to use raw SQL queries, which allowed me to achieve the desired filter. However, I encountered a roadblock when attempting to paginate the results. It seems that raw querysets don't support pagination out of the box.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
queryset = CheckTraModelTotal.objects.raw(sql_query)
page = RawQuerySetPaginator(queryset, 15)
serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: No, how would the ORM know how to paginate an arbitrary query.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth to specify what you are trying to filter, and how that did not work.

Comment: The filter is that I want to add a 2nd condition in the ON clause of a left outer join

modelA LEFT OUTER JOIN `modelB` ON (
 `modelA`.`model_num` = `modelB`.`model_num` AND `modelA`.`displayed_product_no` = `modelB`.`products_seq_no`
)

Comment: Pagination works fine with most `raw` queries. Can you show your whole view including SQL, a very simplified version?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change how you call pagination, if your code sample is accurate: `page = RawQuerySetPaginator(queryset, 15)`

Pagination should have no issue with *most* raw queries.  Ordering and searching are, of course, an issue.

```py
class MyPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 1

qs = User.objects.raw("SELECT id, email FROM user ORDER BY id desc")

paginator = MyPagination()

# page is a list of user objects here
page = paginator.paginate_queryset(qs, request=req)

# generate the list of dict objects for output
serialized_data = UserSerializer(page, many=True).data

# create a Response(), with the `count` and next/prev links
output = paginator.get_paginated_response(serialized_data)
```

Edit: Abdul kindly pointed out it does the count by by fetching all the data.  Makes sense, I didn't think about the query side.  Beware!

```
print(f"total records => {paginator.page.paginator.count}")
```

It may help you in testing, so here is the snippet I used to generate the fake request - you can't just use the output of the APIRequestFactory directly.

```
def make_request():
    from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
    from rest_framework.request import Request
    from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
    req = APIRequestFactory().get("/", {"page": "1"})
    return Request(req, parsers=[JSONParser()])
```

Comment: Note that using the builtin Paginator with Raw Querysets implies fetching all of the data returned by the query from the database instead of only a specific page's data.

Comment: Damn, I didn't even think about that, just noticed it did seem to work fine and probably calling it wrong.  I can't imagine even trying this, it would _have_ to crash somewhere else eventually with a viewset.

Comment: yes that s what it makes it impractical, because unlike fetching only the paginated data from db, paginating with raw query, loads the entire table into the server. I am dealing with some very large tables so this makes it not suitable.

Comment: It's an interesting problem though, replacing both levels of pagination with something that understand this.  It seems doable, but not pleasant - and a sql generator like pypika or sql alchemy core.  Also - did that fix your issue with pagination?  Since you mentioned it doesn't work but it does - just inefficiently.